# how to filter out json array based category type on a data set javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i have an json array and when the the user clicks on a button I want to only display the length of a movie which is the same length, how would I do this?

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "movie_name": "last holidy",
    "date": "2023-10-29",
    "length": ["1 hour 30"],
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "movie_name": "pitch perfect",
    "date": "2023-04-24",
    "length": [
      "2 hours"
    ]
  }
]
```

```html
<button class="movieLength">1 hours</button>
<button class="movieLength">2 hours</button>
```

I can't understand how to do this

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Select the buttons and movies container
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "movie_name": "last holidy",
    "date": "2023-10-29",
    "length": ["1 hour 30"],
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "movie_name": "pitch perfect",
    "date": "2023-04-24",
    "length": [
      "2 hours"
    ]
  }
]

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.movieLength');
const moviesContainer = document.getElementById('movies-container');

// Add click event listener to each button
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const length = button.dataset.length; // Get the selected length
    const matchingMovies = data.filter(movie => movie.length.includes(length)); // Filter the movies based on the selected length

    // Clear the previous content of the movies container
    moviesContainer.innerHTML = '';

    // Display the matching movies
    matchingMovies.forEach(movie => {
      const movieElement = document.createElement('div');
      movieElement.textContent = `${movie.movie_name} (${movie.length[0]})`;
      moviesContainer.appendChild(movieElement);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching based on a string like this can be inconsistent. But here you go:

const twoHourMovies = data.filter(x => x.length === '2 hours');

Comment: how do I get this to work when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

So i am not entirely sure, how you want to display it but if i understand it correctly you want to append the information below the button. To do that i changed your html to match a bit to the following:

```js
    const data = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "movie_name": "last holidy",
            "date": "2023-10-29",
            "length": ["1 hour 30"],
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "movie_name": "pitch perfect",
            "date": "2023-04-24",
            "length": ["2 hours"]
        }
    ];

    const movieList = document.getElementById('movie-list');
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('movie-button');

    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            const lengthToMatch = this.getAttribute('data-length');
            const matchedMovies = data.filter(movie => movie.length.includes(lengthToMatch));
            movieList.innerHTML = '';
            matchedMovies.forEach(movie => {
                const movieItem = document.createElement('div');
                movieItem.classList.add('movie');
                movieItem.innerHTML = `
              <h2>${movie.movie_name}</h2>
              <p class="movie-length">${movie.length}</p>
              <p>${movie.date}</p>
            `;
                movieList.appendChild(movieItem);
            });
        });
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="movie-button" data-length="1 hour 30">1 hour 30</button>
    <button class="movie-button" data-length="2 hours">2 hours</button>
</div>
<div id="movie-list">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it `select` in HTML and do `data.filter` in JS like this:

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "movie_name": "last holidy",
  "date": "2023-10-29",
  "length": ["1 hour 30"],
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "movie_name": "pitch perfect",
  "date": "2023-04-24",
  "length": ["2 hours"]
}];

let movie = document.getElementById('movie');
let moviesLength = document.getElementsByClassName('movieLength');
let first = document.getElementsByClassName('first');
let second = document.getElementsByClassName('second');
let length = document.getElementById('length');
moviesLength[0].onclick = function() {
  let id = parseInt(movie.value);
  length.innerText = data.filter(f => f.id === id).map(m => m.length[0])[0];
}

first[0].onclick = function() {
  let id = parseInt(movie.value);
  same.innerText = data.filter(f => f.id === id).map(m => m.length[0])[0] === first[0].innerText ? 'True' : 'False';
}

second[0].onclick = function() {
  let id = parseInt(movie.value);
  same.innerText = data.filter(f => f.id === id).map(m => m.length[0])[0] === second[0].innerText ? 'True' : 'False';
}
```

```html
<select id="movie">
  <option value="1">last holidy</option>
  <option value="2">pitch perfect</option>
</select>
<button class="movieLength">Show Length</button>
<button class="first">1 hour 30</button>
<button class="second">2 hours</button>
<div>
  Length: <span id="length"></span>
</div>
<div>
  Same: <span id="same"></span>
</div>
```